# Spring Boot: Is it safe to pass many Instances for CommandLineRunner

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm a bit new to Spring Boot. I have an **Application.java** class where I have some code:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    ...

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner App(DBReportRepository dbReportRepository,
                                  ClientRepository clientRepository, FileParser fileParser,
                                       MessagingService messagingService, ClientReportFactoryImpl clientReportFactory) ...
```

I was wondering is it a good practice to pass so many parameters (which are @Services annotated classes) to CommandLineRunner.

Or am I making Spring Boot do too much and there is another way to make Spring Boot be aware of those @Services classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out my spring boot configuration was missing an AppConfig class. Without it I could only use @Autowired with @Component classes or @Service classes which were passed as arguments to CommandLineRunner. I created the AppConfig.java looking like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "your.main.package")
public class AppConfig {
}
```

And after that I could use the @Autowired *everywhere* possible.